# How to change style attribute value in programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have button and I set style from xml now on click of button I want to change style like

```
style="@style/ButtonNotSelected"
```

Place to

```
style="@style/ButtonSelected"
```

programmatically..

Please help..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will better if you use xml and a selector , to get your button change color when it is pressed, you could define an XML file called `res/drawable/my_button.xml`.

**Set** `my_button.xml` **as background to your button.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
  <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

`@drawable/button_pressed` **something like this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#449def"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"
                     android:bottom="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`@drawable/button_normal` **something like this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient android:startColor="#449def" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:angle="270"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp"
                     android:bottom="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
 ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.MyStyle);
 Button button = new Button(newContext);
```

OR

```
 btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button_answer);
 \res\drawable\back_button_answer.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners android:radius="10dip" />
 <!-- background -->

   <gradient
            android:startColor="#D6D7D6"
            android:centerColor="#E2E2E2"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#D6D7D6"
            android:angle="270"
    />

   <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#fff"/>
   </shape>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to create new button i already placed button in xml.